# How to fix dpkg error code (1)

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I keep running into the same error code which isn't letting me do anything. I can't install any software or run any of the fixes that people have suggested on other posts asking the same thing.

When I try to run `sudo apt-get install firefox`, I get the error message

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libmpdec3 libpython3-stdlib libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib
  python3 python3-minimal python3.10 python3.10-minimal
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.

The following additional packages will be installed:
  apparmor dbus dbus-user-session dirmngr fuse3 gnupg gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils
  gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm libassuan0
  libcbor0.8 libdbus-1-3 libedit2 libfido2-1 libfuse3-3 libksba8 liblzo2-2
  libnpth0 libnss-systemd libpam-runtime libpam-systemd libx11-6 libx11-data
  libxau6 libxcb1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxmuu1 lsb-base openssh-client
  pinentry-curses snapd squashfs-tools systemd-hwe-hwdb systemd-sysv udev
  xauth

Suggested packages:
  apparmor-profiles-extra apparmor-utils pinentry-gnome3 tor parcimonie
  xloadimage scdaemon keychain libpam-ssh monkeysphere ssh-askpass
  pinentry-doc zenity | kdialog
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apparmor dbus dbus-user-session dirmngr firefox fuse3 gnupg gnupg-l10n
  gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm
  libassuan0 libcbor0.8 libdbus-1-3 libedit2 libfido2-1 libfuse3-3 libksba8
  liblzo2-2 libnpth0 libnss-systemd libpam-runtime libpam-systemd libx11-6
  libx11-data libxau6 libxcb1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxmuu1 lsb-base
  openssh-client pinentry-curses snapd squashfs-tools systemd-hwe-hwdb
  systemd-sysv udev xauth

0 upgraded, 43 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/29.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 126 MB of additional disk space will be used.

Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Setting up systemd (249.11-0ubuntu3.11) ...
cp: '/etc/resolv.conf' and '/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf' are the same file
dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 installed systemd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Using a forced installation doesn't work. I get the same error when I try to install any web browser (chrome, chromium, brave etc)

Reconfiguring dpkg DOES NOT WORK.
`sudo dpkg --configure -a` produces this error:

```
Setting up python3 (3.10.6-1~22.04) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.10...
dpkg-query: package 'gedit' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of gedit
error running python rtupdate hook gedit
dpkg-query: package 'hplip-data' is not installed

Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of hplip-data
error running python rtupdate hook hplip-data
dpkg-query: package 'ibus-table' is not installed

Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of ibus-table
error running python rtupdate hook ibus-table
dpkg-query: package 'ibus' is not installed

Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of ibus
error running python rtupdate hook ibus
dpkg-query: package 'python3-uno' is not installed

Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of python3-uno
error running python rtupdate hook python3-uno
dpkg-query: package 'rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar' is not installed

Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar
error running python rtupdate hook rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar
dpkg-query: package 'rhythmbox-plugins' is not installed

Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of rhythmbox-plugins
error running python rtupdate hook rhythmbox-plugins
dpkg-query: package 'system-config-printer-common' is not installed

Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of system-config-printer-common
error running python rtupdate hook system-config-printer-common
dpkg-query: package 'system-config-printer' is not installed

Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of system-config-printer
error running python rtupdate hook system-config-printer
dpkg-query: package 'ubuntu-drivers-common' is not installed

Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of ubuntu-drivers-common
error running python rtupdate hook ubuntu-drivers-common
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 4
Setting up systemd (249.11-0ubuntu3.11) ...
cp: '/etc/resolv.conf' and '/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf' are the same file
dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 installed systemd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 systemd
```

I'm at my wit's end. Reconfiguring is the only solution that people have suggested. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using, and what is the system's python3 version (`/usr/bin/python3 --version`)

Comment: Edit your question to show complete output. The edits omit vital information.

Comment: The Ubuntu version is 22.04.3 LTS. The system's python3 is 3.9.18

Comment: I've edited it to show complete outputs

Comment: Please add the output of `apt policy python3`